# Run vim command from the command line

Tags: vim, batch

I need to do the following in several files: `dt{%lx:wq`, i.e.,

1. delete to the first `{`
2. find the matching `}`
3. delete the next character
4. save and exit

how do I do this from the command line without opening the screen?

`vi -c 'dt{%lx:wq'` fails with the obvious

```
E492: Not an editor command: dt{%lx:wq
```

I guess I need to convert each command - `dt{`, `%`, `l`, `x` - to an `ex` command. How do I find the commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use both `vi` and `ex`, for example:

```
ex -s +'norm dt{%lx' -cwq foo
```

For `vi`, just add `-e` (for Ex mode):

```
vi -es +'norm dt{%lx' -cwq foo
```

So to make your examples work, basically you need to add `norm`/`normal` which executes commands in Normal mode (as you would be typing in Vi).

The key parameters are:

- `-s` - Silent mode which won't open the screen. Useful for working in the terminal.
- `-e` - Ex-mode (necessary for `vi`/`vim` commands) as `ex` have it already by default
- `-cwq` - Nicer way of doing `:wq`

If you've still problems, add `-V` for verbosity.

For further examples, check:

- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467) at Vi SE
- [Does Ex mode have any practical use?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/457/467) at Vi SE